# Generate Pdf with Arabic fonts

Tags: reactjs, pdf, utf-8, arabic, jspdf

I want to download a pdf file with Arabic fonts in react and haven't found any solution. I am currently using jsPdf but it's not rendering Arabic font's properly

```
let doc = new PDFDocument
let doc = new pdf();
doc.setFontSize(10);
doc.rect(20, 20, doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 40, 
doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 40, 'S');
doc.setTextColor(128,0,128);
doc.text("Date", 30, 25);
doc.text(this.state.date, 50, 25);
doc.text("السلام عليكم", 30, 35);
doc.text("Quantity", 120, 35);
let distance = 30;
doc.save("data.pdf");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can  you add jsPdf  link

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf

Answer (score 2):

First download a desired font. Then go to https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html

and convert & download the file. Move it to your project directory and import it in the desired module.

You can also take the large string and put it in a variable `const myFont = "VVV....VVV"`

Then use it like this.

```
   doc.addFileToVFS("MyFont.ttf", myFont);
   doc.addFont("MyFont.ttf", "MyFont", "normal");
   doc.setFont("MyFont");
```

Now you will need to right-align the text.

```
doc.text("Arabic Text", 200, 20, "right");
//OR
doc.text("Arabic Text", 200, 20, { align : "right" } ); 
/* 
200 is the x coordinate and marks the starting position of the text from right.
y coordinate is the distance from the top of the page.
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding {lang: 'value'} Option ?

```
doc.text(['لا إله إلا الله محمد رسول الله', 'لا إله إلا الله', 'a'], 100, 100, { lang: 'ar' });
```

Comment: Yes but still not rendering properly.

Answer (score 1):

The Arabic font can be printed into pdf by following these steps

1. Convert HTML to canvas using [html2canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas)
2. Convert the image to pdf using [jspdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf)

   ```
   const input = document.getElementById('divIdToPrint');    
   html2canvas(input)
         .then((canvas) => {
           const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
           const pdf = new jsPDF();
           pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0);
           pdf.save("download.pdf");  
     });
   ```

Details in this [blog](https://medium.com/@shivekkhurana/how-to-create-pdfs-from-react-components-client-side-solution-7f506d9dfa6d)

[Demo link on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4798tj?file=components%2FSinglePage.js)

Answer (score 0):

Add this styling to the wrapper object to properly render arabic font:

```
letter-spacing: normal !important;
```

source : [Arabic font rendering](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/948)