# Font-family does not render in production after download PDF using jsPDF in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, dom-to-image

ReactJS with jsPDF download does not render font-family.

jsPDF is working well on development but in the production version. I am facing a font-family missing issue after downloading the pdf. Showing below error in console.

```
Error while reading CSS rules from file:///Users/rahulshinde/Documents/hdfclife/offline-quote-fe/dist/assets/css/main.css SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
```

Found some solutions online by adding the following attribute in link tag.

```
crossorigin="anonymous"
```

But it seems it required server to run code. I find this is not a good solution.

Comment: import the font as Base64 encoded

Comment: I have Investigated further, This issue occurs due to domtoimage npm package. 

@ZahirMasoodi Thank you for your reply can you please share any example which will be helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66024218/14047838
Maybe it will help.

Comment: I have converted DOM to image (JPEG) which is causing the problem. Not with JSPDF.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet @RahulShinde, It will very much helpful.